# Unable to load Recipe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance

Tags: openrewrite

I am trying to create own OpenRewrite recipes by follow up [recipe-development-environment](https://docs.openrewrite.org/authoring-recipes/recipe-development-environment) instruction but getting below error while running my recipe:-

```
[ERROR] Recipe validation error in com.sk.app.MyMergeYaml: Unable to load Recipe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `com.sk.app.MyMergeYaml` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
     at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    [ERROR] Recipe validation error in com.sk.app.MyMergeYaml: Unable to load Recipe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `com.sk.app.MyMergeYaml` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
     at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    [ERROR] Recipe validation error in com.sk.app.MyMergeYaml: Unable to load Recipe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `com.sk.app.MyMergeYaml` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
     at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    [ERROR] Recipe validation errors detected as part of one or more activeRecipe(s). Execution will continue regardless.
```

I am able to run given sample [SayHelloRecipe](https://docs.openrewrite.org/authoring-recipes/writing-a-java-refactoring-recipe)  but in similar way I can not run my custom `MyMergeYaml` recipe. I have not customized anything in [MergeYaml](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/e77eabd1cbe3479de4f4d6e52728db2d6877399d/rewrite-yaml/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/yaml/MergeYaml.java) recipe yet except class name, first just willing to run same recipe with my custom project to test the structure.

Trying through my maven command:

`mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:dryRun -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=com.sk.app:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT -Drewrite.activeRecipes=com.yourorg.sayHelloToFooBar`

Below is my defined Yaml:-

```
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.yourorg.sayHelloToFooBar
recipeList:
  - com.sk.app.SayHelloRecipe:  #working
      fullyQualifiedClassName: com.manish.mywebclientrest.myRestApplication
      
  - com.sk.app.MyMergeYaml:  #Not working
      key: $.stages.parameters
      yaml: |-
        openJdkVersion: 17
```